# need suggestion on how to correctly design hierarchy for a game I'm create

Tags: javascript, jquery, hierarchy

So i am creating a little game(never done so before) but it got my attention and got me curious so here i am.

i am trying to design hierarchy for objects within the game.

Some on the objects i have so far.

```
/* this is the basic object - every object in game will have that */
var fnObject = function (node){
    this.nNode = node || '';
    this.id = '';
    this.sType = 'pc'/*pc,npc,physics,obstacle*/;
    this.oPosition = {
        marginTop : 0,
        marginLeft : 0
    };
    /*
    * and more properties. 
    * */
}
/* not all objects will have those */
var fnPhysics = function(){
    this.iFriction = '';
    this.iAcceleration = '';
    this.iGravity = '';
    this.iWind = '';
    this.iIncline  = '';
    this.iSpeed = 1;
    this.iMoveDistant = 5;
    /*
     * and more properties. 
     * */
}

/* Only objects that can move will have those */
var fnControls = function (){
    this.fnGetMvDist = function (){
        //..
    }
    this.fnDoMove = function(){
        //..
    };
    this.fnMoveRight = function(){
        //..
    }
}

/* not all objects will have those */
var fnStats = function(){
    this.hp = 100;
    this.manaLeft = 100;
    this.livesLeft = 5;
    /*
     * and more properties. 
     * */
}
```

how can i construct good hierarchy out of those. i mean some objects wont have all of those and some will.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for OOP class inheritance which JS does not have syntax for. There are several ways to emulate this (google JS OOP) here is just one way to achieve it:

```
var fnPhysics = function(){
    var fnObjectInstance = new fnObject();
    fnObjectInstance.iFriction = '';
    fnObjectInstance.iAcceleration = '';
    fnObjectInstance.iGravity = '';
    fnObjectInstance.iWind = '';
    fnObjectInstance.iIncline  = '';
    fnObjectInstance.iSpeed = 1;
    fnObjectInstance.iMoveDistant = 5;
    return fnObjectInstance;
}
```

Comment: well i am trying to learn inheritance while doing this, this however isnt what i am looking for thanks.